# measure time a function takes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, time, timeit

Is there some library in python that lets you easily measure the time a function takes in python. i.e. an example would be you have the function `foo()` and just pass it in as an argument to another function as such,`measure_time( foo() )`. And this should now run the `foo()` function as well as measure the time it takes for `foo()` to reach completion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long does my Python application take to run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444004/how-long-does-my-python-application-take-to-run)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/how-do-i-measure-elapsed-time-in-python