# Python Help: total special numbers

Tags: python, pycharm

I was writing code which finds special numbers (prime numbers between 1-10) and the code functions however I want it to list out how many numbers. Right now it says:

```
Enter smaller number (m): 4
Enter the larger number (n): 7
Special numbers: [5, 7]
Special numbers Brute force: [5, 7]
```

However I want it to say "special numbers = 2: [5,7]".

I tried adding an if statement but didn't know how to add it in to my code, I'll list the code below.

```py
def main():
    m = int(input("Enter smaller number (m): "))
    n = int(input("Enter the larger number (n): "))
    if m >= n:
        print("Error: First number should be smaller than second")
    special_nums = locate_special_numbers(m, n)

    if len(special_nums) <= 5:
        print("Special numbers are:", special_nums)
    else:
        first_three = special_nums[:3]
        last_three = special_nums[-3:]
        print("First three smallest special numbers:", first_three)
        print("Last three biggest special numbers:", last_three)

    # Brute force approach
    special_numbers_brute_force = locate_special_numbers(m, n)
    print("Special numbers Brute force:", special_numbers_brute_force)


# lines 33-39 are not executing as expected
def amount_of_special_numbers(m, n):
    amount_of_special_numbersList = []
    for num in range(m, n + 1):
        if prime(num) and mirrored(num):
            amount_of_special_numbersList.append(num)
            print(
                "The total number of special number is:",
                len(amount_of_special_numbersList),
            )
            # Return the list after the first special number is found
            return amount_of_special_numbersList


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: please format all of your code, not just some of your code

Comment: You're only printing the value of `special_numbers_brute_force`, which is `[5, 7]`. Instead you want it print the length of `special_numbers_brute_force` as well as the value in a specific format. The nicest way to do this is to look at formatted strings, or so-called f-strings. You can also just concatenate many strings together with `+`, which may seem easier to write but will be harder to read and understand once written.

Comment: You haven't defined the functions `prime()`, `mirrored` and `locate_special_numbers(m, n)` in the above code

Comment: the code isnt shown fully for some reason by i have defined the functions

Comment: `return amount_of_special_numbersList` What is the point of having a list, when it is guaranteed to only contain one number??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your code a bit and wrote the `is_prime(num)` and `locate_special_numbers(m, n)` functions.

```
def is_prime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(2, int(num ** 0.5) + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def locate_special_numbers(m, n):
    prime_numbers = []
    for num in range(m, n + 1):
        if is_prime(num):
            prime_numbers.append(num)
    return prime_numbers

def main():
    m = int(input("Enter smaller number (m): "))
    n = int(input("Enter the larger number (n): "))
    if m >= n:
        print("Error: First number should be smaller than second")
    special_nums = locate_special_numbers(m, n)

    if len(special_nums) <= 5:
        print("Special numbers are:",len(special_nums), ":", special_nums)
    else:
        first_three = special_nums[:3]
        last_three = special_nums[-3:]
        print("First three smallest special numbers:", first_three)
        print("Last three biggest special numbers:", last_three)

    # Brute force approach
    special_numbers_brute_force = locate_special_numbers(m, n)
    print("Special numbers Brute force:", special_numbers_brute_force)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This gave me the output of:

```
Enter smaller number (m): 4
Enter the larger number (n): 7
Special numbers are: 2 : [5, 7]
Special numbers Brute force: [5, 7]
```

As you can see in the code, `print("Special numbers are:",len(special_nums), ":", special_nums)` would work for you. If you wanted to use formatted strings  `print("Special numbers are: %d" %len(special_nums), ":", special_nums)` would also work although it would be harder to understand.
Hope this helps!

Comment: hey i tired liking your post but i dont have enough rep :/ thank you regardless i really appreciate it!!

Comment: if you could accept my answer it would make me very happy ;) plz

Comment: ive accepted it! could you tell me how to add a timer ive imported time and defined my start and end fuction and done a final end_time - start_time but it still doesnt give a time just 0.0 seconds

Comment: you could do `start_time = time.time()` at the beginning and `print("My program took", time.time() - start_time, "to run")` at the end as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12444018/22409380) indicates.